# How to initialize a handler in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, handler

I've been trying to do timed tasks with a handler in Android Studio, but when I try to initialize it, this happens:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {

        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {

        }
    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {

    }
};
```

Whenever I look at online examples where people use Handlers to execute code at intervals, their declarations look as such:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

How do I avoid the big jumble of methods within the Handler?

Comment: Try to check 1: if you can't just remove the methods, or 2: check if you use the Handler class you think you are using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use `java.util.logging.Handler` instead of `android.os.Handler`. Changing which one you import at the top of the file should fix your problem.

The auto-complete should show you which packages you will be importing from, so watch out for that in the future.